# How do I link_to all objects that have a certain attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a `Connection` model, that has a `request_status` attribute. That `request_status` can be one of 4 options: `accepted, pending, rejected, removed`.

Without creating a route for each status, and dedicated actions in my controller and all that jazz, on my `Connections#Index` page, what I want to do is just create 4 tabs and when I click on each one it lists all connections that have that `request_status`.

So imagine I have these links:

```
    <li class="profile__navigation-tab is-active"><a href="/user/videos">Active</a></li>
    <li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos">Pending</a></li>
    <li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos">Rejected</a></li>
    <li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos">Removed</a></li>
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `link_to` you would want something like this:

```
= link_to "Active", connections_path( request_status: :active )
```

And then, rather than repeat for each of the items, you could do something like this:

```
<% %w[active pending rejected removed].each do |status| %>
  <% is_active = "is-active" if params[:request_status] == status %>
  <%= content_tag :li, link_to( status.titleize, connections_path( request_status: status )), class: ["profile__navigation-tab", is_active].compact %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For the record, I really love this version. I had to select it as the answer. It is so nice and elegant and gave me exactly what I want even though I didn't explicitly ask for it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your index action to something similar to:

```
@connections = <Your current logic to get all connections>
@connections = @connections.where(request_status: params[:request_status]) if params[:request_status])
```

Then all you have to do is to add extra param to your urls:

```
<li class="profile__navigation-tab is-active"><a href="/user/videos?request_status=active">Active</a></li>
<li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos?request_status=pending">Pending</a></li>
<li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos?request_status=rejected">Rejected</a></li>
<li class="profile__navigation-tab"><a href="/user/videos?request_status=removed">Removed</a></li>
```

Comment: I love this approach. Thanks!